# Terraform azuread Service principle permission permission

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, terraform

I am working with terraform tools to create Azure active directory applications. Now in order to do that I need to create a service principal with permissions that can be used to create an application via terraform.

The permission that requires is **Application.ReadWrite.All** but it cannot be given (Company restriction as it's not specific to my things )as it can be used to manipulate all apps (some other team in the company who is using the same AD) under the active directory.

Is there any way of creating a service principle w.r.t to azure ad + azure subscription so that my service principle will have the right to manipulate all apps under my subscription?

Although **Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy**  this one is there but it's not enough to create apps and all.

Any other way around is getting such access is not feasible in the company which is very much in security.

Comment: The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference does suggest that `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` should have the ability to create an application: "`Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy: Create an application (POST /v1.0/applications)`"

Comment: Wait a minute - the permissions you're talking about are to grant an application the permission to create/manipulate apps. If you're running Terraform under a service principal, you should be able to assign a role like `Contributor` at the subscription level to the service principal?

Answer (score 0):

As **WaitingForGuacamole** mentioned in the comments `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy` can be also ***used to create the apps in Azure AD***. Giving the ***Service Principal*** `Contributor` access in subscription will give you ***access to create/ manage resources*** by using `terraform-provider-azurerm` but it ***won't give access to create/manage Azure AD resources*** using `terraform-provider-azuread`.

***I tested with only `application.readwrite.ownedby` permission to create add app using the below code :***

```
provider "azuread" {
client_id = "25a29c83-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-e2bbaed816f1"
client_secret = "F0T7Q~cjAxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqbS"
tenant_id = "ab078f81-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx620b694ded30"
}

# Create an application
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
display_name     ="aaaa"
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]